# filter news and events with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of news and events in two seperate div, and then I have a filternavigation to tick whether you only want to see News or Events.
So in my controller I've set $scope.showNews = true and $scope.showEvents = true, as I want to display both for starters. In my navigation I've set this:

```
<li><a ng-click="showNews==true && showEvents == false" title="News" href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="showEvents==true && showNews == false" title="Events" href="#">Events</a></li>
```

and then in my news containing div I have this:

```
<section ng-show="showNews == true" class="ribbon grid-layout-section clearfix 1-cell ng-cloak" >
```

and also in my events containing div I have

```
<section ng-show="showEvents == true" class="ribbon grid-layout-section clearfix 1-cell ng-cloak">
```

However, I can't really get the filter to work, nothing happens when clicking news or events in my filter navigation. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it, you're doing a conditional in your `ng-click`'s so they're practically doing nothing.

```
<li><a ng-click="showNews = true; showEvents = false" title="News" href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a ng-click="showEvents = true; showNews = false" title="Events" href="#">Events</a></li>
```

This will actually set the variables instead of comparing them, to actually monitor what happens in the `ng-click`'s even better is to add a function to your controller's scope and test that function. But this would work!

Considering that you would only show one `div` at a time, you could also do a bit cleaner approach like so:

```
<li><a ng-click="show = 'news'" title="News" href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a ng-click="show = 'events'" title="Events" href="#">Events</a></li>

<div ng-show="show === 'news'">News</div>
<div ng-show="show === 'events'">Events</div>
```

**EDIT**: controller approach: https://jsfiddle.net/yttrms75/

Comment: Awesome, thx alot :) How would I go about it, if I wanted to add it to the controller?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)